# why Node-key-sender doesn't work after build?

Tags: node.js, electron, node-modules, electron-builder

I have used node-key-sender in an electron application. I works fine in my system. I have build it using electron-builder and installed the app in other systems. when I try to run the application it shows the error message

libva error: vaGetDriverNameByIndex() failed with unknown libva error, driver_name = (null)
[67890:0207/194700.271830:ERROR:gl_surface_presentation_helper.cc(260)] GetVSyncParametersIfAvailable() failed for 1 times!
[67890:0207/194703.274367:ERROR:gl_surface_presentation_helper.cc(260)] GetVSyncParametersIfAvailable() failed for 2 times!
[67890:0207/194705.282643:ERROR:gl_surface_presentation_helper.cc(260)] GetVSyncParametersIfAvailable() failed for 3 times!

I have googled and found it is related to graphics configuration. is there any dependency for node-key-sender with system configuration

I tried to emit the keypress events using node-key-sender

Comment: This is not in any way related to `node-key-sender`. Since you're using Electron, this is an error generated by Chrome (used by Electron). Is this on a different machine than your development machine? Have you had success simply running Chrome on this machine?